# Sequelize - afterBulkUpdate() how get if updated or not

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

How I know inside a hook afterBulkUpdate() if instance User updated or not?

`UserController.js`

```
const [isUpdated] = await User.update(
    fields,
    {where}
);

// Where I know if updated or not! isUpdated is 1 when updated, 0 when not updated
```

`User.js`

```
// But inside a Model how I know if updated or not?
User.addHook('afterBulkUpdate', (options) => {
    // user.isUpdated?
});
```

I couldn't use afterUpdate(), doesn't run to me, even using `individualHooks: true` like this:

`UserController.js`

```
const [isUpdated] = await User.update(
    fields,
    {where, individualHooks: true}
);
```

I am using MySQL. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
const user = sequelize.define("user",
    {
      first_name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, trim: true },
      ...
     
    },
      hooks: {
        // afterUpdate(instance, options) {
        //   let changed = instance._changed;
        //   console.log(changed, options);
        // }
      },
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

After @Wang Liang answer, I concluded:

`beforeUpdate()` execute only if WHERE of SQL is true.

`afterUpdate()` also execute only if WHERE of SQL is true.

Example:

```
const [isUpdated] = await User.update(
    fields,
    {
        individualHooks: true, // Needs to execute `beforeUpdate()` and `afterUpdate()`
        where: {
            userId: 0 // ID does not exists in DB
        }
    });
```

In this case `beforeUpdate()` and `afterUpdate()` does not execute, because `userId = 0` is `false`. Can be with another condition false on WHERE.

Remember: `isUpdated` return number of affected rows. Not if can updated or not (because of WHERE).

---

`beforeBulkUpdate()` is always executed after update no mather what.

`afterBulkUpdate()` is always executed before update no mather what.

---

So my solution is:

```
User.addHook('beforeBulkUpdate', (options) => {
    options.model.updated = false; // Not updated yet
});

User.addHook('afterUpdate', (instance, options) => {
    options.model.updated = true; // Execute the updated, because WHERE is true
});
```

On Controller:

```
const [isUpdated] = await User.update(
    fields,
    {
        individualHooks: true, // remember this
        where
    });

console.log(User.updated); 
console.log(isUpdated);
```

- When does NOT affect any rows, but WHERE is true: `User.updated = true` `isUpdated = 0`
- When affects any rows and WHERE is true: `User.updated = true` `isUpdated = N` (N is affected rows)
- When has not changes in data and WHERE is false: `User.updated = false` `isUpdated = 0`
- When has changes in data and WHERE is false: `User.updated = false` `isUpdated = 0`

Of course when WHERE is false, does not mather is has changed data or not.